# How to add my own theme for Action Bar Scherlock android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to have an `Actionbar` with white background and red color text for app name.

I am using `ActionBarSherlock library`.

Is it possible to do like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your style here: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
And then just apply it to your actionbar: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html